# Opening my app with 'yarn start' : error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner with React.
My first app as exercice work well. But for next exercices  I have to download a file from GitHub.

[This one for exemple:](https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/7008001-Debutez-avec-React/tree/P2C2-Solution)

So, I download the file, unzip it, open the unzipped file from vsCode, everything opens, everything looks ok.

I do 'yarn start' as with my first app and this is what is displayed in my Terminal:

[image]

What does it mean ?

Comment: did you do `yarn install` first? And also it would be much more useful for us to read the error in English to be able to help you

Comment: I had done "npm install --global yarn". So Yarn should be install for all projects, aren't it ? I tried to change the language in the terminal but without success. This is the translate of error message: "'React-script' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a command file."

Comment: `npm install --global yarn` is another. This is for installing `yarn` as a tool. But `yarn install` is for installing your project dependencies

Comment: From where (wich folder) I have to make 'yarn install' ?  I have really lot of difficulties to understand how to install this kind of tool (saas react nodejs npm yarn sodo ... ) Sometime we have to install in local sometime not... I took some lesson for how to use the 'Terminal' but i'm not aware with how all this installings works exactelly. Is there somes cours to learn how all this things are organised in order to know how to install this tools ?

Comment: read more about installing dependencies and package.json. You should run `yarn install` in the folder where you have you package.json